# Javascript alert() in a pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an anchor tag whose click event calls a JavaScript function, which opens a pop up window.

Now when the user clicks the close button of the pop up window I want to generate an `alert()`, which asks whether the user wants to close the pop up window or not

Using the below code the alert is generate in the parent window rather than the pop up

```
<script>
function  openForm()
{
    var new_window = window.open('file:///C:/Users/Tejora/Desktop/test.html','popup''width=825,height=585,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=50,top=0');
    new_window.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
           alert("Are you sure you want to close the window");      }
}
</script>


 <a href="#" onclick="openForm()">Click</a>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The function you're looking for instead is called 'confirm', which is kind of an alert, but asks for a yes/no user input.

Comment: Use `return confirm("Are you sure ...");` to present a confirmation dialog instead of an alert as mentioned by @doldt

Comment: `confirm` and `alert` calls should NOT be made in the `onbeforeunload` event handler: "Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload

Comment: Well, `onbeforeunload` also gets fired when you hit the back button or refresh the page. I do not think there is ANY way you can trap browser close event!! How about using a custom pop  instead of a new window? That would give you all the control you need.

Comment: @ArinCool He's opening a popup. Presumably, there is no additional navigation inside the popup, and new windows start out with a clean History, so the back button doesn't work. Your point still stands when it comes to refreshing though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a string is returned from the `onbeforeunload` handler, the browser will display a confirmation dialog with that message. Replace this line:

`alert("Are you sure you want to close the window");`

With this:

`return "Are you sure you want to close the window?";`

**[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload)** is the relevant documentation.

Comment: when I replaced the alert with return, no pop up is generated

Comment: I've just tested the solution and it works just fine. Please paste your new code. Also, you have an error in your example code, there should be a comma after 'popup': `'popup''width=825 ...`

Comment: Thanks its works but is there any way to change the text it says "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." as well as the buttons text

Comment: You are using Firefox, right? Unfortunately, Firefox completely ignores the text you return, ever since version 4. Google Chrome displays your text, but also adds an additional message of its own. And you cannot change the button labels in any browser. There is no way around this, sorry, it's meant to protect browser users from malicious websites (and rightly so). If you want complete control, you should simulate a popup with a DOM element. Otherwise, you're out of luck.